# Default Selection of first item in Listview

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listView and item selected event.Here I would like make my first item to be selected by default on appearing the list on view.Later selecting other item it should work normally.

```
        ListView listView = new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = staticSpListDetailses,

            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {

                var nameLabel = new Label();
                nameLabel.FontSize = 18;
                nameLabel.WidthRequest = 180;
                nameLabel.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start;
                nameLabel.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
                nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");

                var subtitlelabel = new Label();
                subtitlelabel.FontSize = 16;
                subtitlelabel.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start;
                subtitlelabel.TextColor = Color.Silver;
                subtitlelabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "SubTitle");

                var arrowmarklabel = new Label();
                arrowmarklabel.FontSize = 20;
                arrowmarklabel.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand;
                arrowmarklabel.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                arrowmarklabel.TextColor = Color.Black;
                arrowmarklabel.Text = ">";
                arrowmarklabel.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;

                var arrowmarklabel1 = new Label();
                arrowmarklabel1.WidthRequest = 90;

                var insideStackLayout = new StackLayout
                {
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Spacing = 5,
                    Children =
                    {
                        nameLabel,subtitlelabel
                    }
                };

                var image = new Image();
                image.Scale = 0.8;
                image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "ImageSourceUrl");

                return new ViewCell
                {
                    View = new StackLayout
                    {
                        Padding = new Thickness(10,0, 5, 0),
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        Children = {

                            new StackLayout {
                                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                                Orientation=StackOrientation.Horizontal,

                                Children = {
                                    image,insideStackLayout,arrowmarklabel
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            })
        };
```

here is my Itemselected event:

```
listView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var data = ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem as StaticListDetails;
            Detail = data.page;               
        };
```

What are the changes required to my code to make first item to be selected default in list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listView.SelectedItem = staticSpListDetailses?.FirstOrDefault()
```